# How to use Spring transactions with plain old jdbc connection without Spring jdbc template?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-transactions

We have an old EJB based web application which we are supposed to migrate into Spring boot. For database connectivity, it is a plain old jdbc connection approach as of now.

We want to use Spring transactions and remove EJB transactions but willing to keep plain old jdbc connectivity same. In short we don't want to make changes in our DAO layer to convert plain old jdbc to Spring JdbcTemplate.

Please note that we have our own connection pooling algorithm and we create connection object and close it in the pool.

Along with this we want our application to be multi-tenant that can work with multiple databases on the basis of 'tenantID' that we will provide.

I actually tried to implement this but it is not working. I had to manually do con.commit(); and con.rollback();

Is there any way to use Spring transactions with plain old jdbc connectivity with above scenario?

Comment: what do you gain keeping fragments of old technology, keep old JDBC connection is not a good idea, whatever your old application does, spring boot can do better

Comment: We'd probably need a bit more information about your custom connection pool implementation. A good starting point for documentation would be [DataSourceTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html)